# An unlikely series of events

Tags: visual, knowledge, game

This series of 8 events would be rather unlikely, but possible. They are all related to the same thing. What are they?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Hint 1:**

> 3 of the events are the same.

**Hint 2:**

> [image]

**Hint 3:**

> <s>Check the tags.</s> It has something to do with a game.

**Hint 4:**

> 4 of the pictures represent one word events (including the 3 that are the same).
>  3 of the pictures represent events that are one word and a number.
>  1 of the pictures represents an event that is two words and a number.
>
>  Other than the three that are the same, each of the pictures represents an event that is unique in the sequence. The order matters.

Comment: Hmmm.  Hint 3 suggests we are supposed to "... [determine] the winner in a (typically combinatorial) multi-player game."

Comment: @axavio - Well, not really determining the winner. But it has to do with a game. And if you can crack the sequence you can probably figure out who has a very good chance of winning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure of the outline but am missing many of the details. This is

> the bidding in a game of bridge.

In order, we have

Talleyrand

> No idea. He's wearing a kinda diamond-shaped thing (-> *one diamond*?) but I expect it's a handkerchief. He presumably has *one heart* unless he was secretly a Time Lord, but that doesn't seem sufficient.

Cat

> Again no idea. Again, the cat surely has one heart but this doesn't help. (Or it could be, as Penguino observes, *one spayed* cat. Please, no.)

Political protest

> These three people must be *three no-Trumps*.

Baseball field

> I assume this is *four diamonds*, though I always thought the whole thing was a single diamond. (This particular place has a "Diamond Club", which is entertaining but I don't see how it helps. There's at least one other club associated with Safeco Field, namely the Terrace Club; perhaps there are more and this is actually *four clubs*, or perhaps our political thing is only *one no-Trump* and this one is *two clubs*.)

Glass of whisky on the rocks

> Clearly this is a *double*.

Eric Cartman as hallway monitor

> Must be a *pass*, perhaps for reasons that would be apparent if I'd seen this episode of South Park.

Barack Obama's signature

> Clearly another *pass* (the presidential signature being a crucial step in the passing of US legislation).

A plate of uneaten creamy dessert

> Presumably another *pass* because whoever it was for hasn't eaten it (i.e., has passed on it).

As for the likely result,

> it's hard to be sure since I haven't figured out the first couple of bids, but I don't much fancy declarer's chances here, especially if the opening bid really was 1D. I suspect an attempted convention gone awry. But I'm a very rusty bridge player.

Concerning the hints:

> Hint 1: three passes. Hint 2: the picture of course shows a *dummy*. Hint 3: Something to do with a game, indeed. Hint 4: obvious.

Comment: If the cat is female and has been de-sexed then it has been spayed...so 1 spade

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too. And rejected it as too horrible even to mention. I really hope it's wrong...

Comment: The last image is probably supposed to be considered a **pas**try

Comment: I meant horrible because of the ghastly pun, the dubious grammar, and the fact that spayed-ness is in no way apparent from the picture, rather than horrible because one shouldn't spay cats.

Comment: Well, pass-try would be right up there with "one spayed", I guess. That's another one I hope is wrong. As for 3 -- there are three people in the picture, with their faces obscured. If that's not the intended number, I don't really see that there's anything to indicate what *is* the intended number.

Comment: no need to delete anything, I think

Comment: (already deleted, no loss, they were seen when they looked like they made sense)

Comment: Maaaaaybe, but "declarer" just means the first player (of the partnership that wins the bidding) to mention the suit they end up playing in -- it's not a *bid*, nor even an *event*, so I don't think that could fit here.

Comment: This is correct! Talleyrand had a *club* foot. The cat is indeed *apayed* (all calico cats are female, and only female cats can be spayed -- males are neutered). Correct on 3 no trump and 4 diamond. All you need to know about Cartman is that he's a hall monitor, so would demand a hall *pass*. The pastries are 2 cream puffs, and there's an expression in certain circles "puff, puff, pass". I guess I made the clues too obtuse should've put a couple easy ones.

Comment: I knew Talleyrand was lame, but didn't know it was a club foot.

Answer (score 6):

I think I got most of it!

First image: a portrait of [Charles Maurice de Talleyrand-Périgord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Maurice_de_Talleyrand-P%C3%A9rigord), famous for saying *I am more afraid of an army of one hundred sheep led by a lion than an army of one hundred lions led by a sheep.*
First event:

> Paris is overcome by an army of sheep, led by one lion whom the media dub *Aslan*.

Second image: a calico cat
Second event:

> Domesticated animals throughout Europe join Aslan's cause, disturbing the peace in London, Madrid, and Rome.

Third image: Farmers protesting new GMO regulations prohibiting Donald Trump from marketing himself as the most presidential tomato.
Third event:

> Trump loses his bid for the presidency, and crops across Europe and North America are devastated by the growing animal rebellion.

Fourth image: Safeco field
Fourth event:

> Seattle becomes the first city in the U.S. to ban and ostracize all non-human animals, and its high sales taxes are lifted from all meat products. Also, the Mariners win the World Series.

Fifth image: whiskey tumbler
Fifth event:

> As the world's supply of grains declines, alcohol production across the world halts.

Sixth image: Cartman from *South Park* as [Dawg the Hallway Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Teacher_Bangs_a_Boy)
Sixth event:

> I've never seen the show... not really sure what to make of this.

Seventh image: *Chief of Animal Relocation* Barack Obama's signature
Seventh event:

> Barry O is abducted by an animal militia, following a betrayal by his once domesticated dog [Bo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo_(dog)).

Eight image: a cream puff
Eight event:

> still working on this one...

Comment: LOL, I like it :-)! But, no, the events are tied to a specific thing, and aren't exactly "events" of a world-changing nature.